# Datatables with Node JS Express and PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, datatable

I'm a complete novice and appreciate your input in advance. I've set myself a goliath task of building my first full-stack app. I'm trying to link my express app, PostgreSQL db with Datatables. The API fetches the data and logs in the console as it should, however, the table is not showing any data whatsoever. I feel that I'm missing a single step. Can anyone help me out please?

Here's my code:

Index.ejs

```
'''
  <div class="orderTable">
         <table id="myTable" class="display">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Id</th>
                    <th>order_type</th>
                    <th>Timeframe</th>
                    <th>Max Trade Size</th>
                    <th>Market</th>
                    <th>KoF Timeframe</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            </tbody>-->
        </table>
    </div>

'''
```

Index.js

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

```
//midlleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //req.body
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));


app.listen(5000, () => {
console.log("server running on port 5000")
```

});

//Routing//

```
app.get('/getOrder', db.getOrder);`
```

orders.js

```
 const getOrder = (request, response) => {
     pool.query(
        'SELECT * FROM orderbook_table')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.rows)
        response.render('index', { orders: res.rows });


    }).catch(error => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
    })
}
```

Front-end Datatable Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/getOrder",

        },
        "columns": [
            { 'data': "order_type" },

        ]
    });
});
```

Console log data

```
[
  {
    id: 186,
    market: 'AAPL - Apple Inc. Common Stock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ',
    order_type: 'Call                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ',
    trade_amount: '2000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ',
    strike_price: null,
    filled_status: null,
    kof_frame: null,
    time_frame: '30 mins                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ',
    expiration_date: null,
    'settles_in ': null,
    timestamp: 'Mon Aug 02 2021 11:01:48 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)                                                                                                                                                                                               ',
    order_status: null
  }
]
```

'''

Answer (score -1):

It's missing the step where you display the data on the UI. Since you are using [ejs](https://ejs.co/) you can use it as:

1. npm package - `npm install ejs`
2. cli - `ejs ./template_file.ejs -f data_file.json -o ./output.html`
3. browser - `<% if (user) { %><h2><%= user.name %></h2><% } %>`

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).